# Material design: change select action for the whole tab button, not only for the label

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, material-design

I'm trying to show a menu by clicking on the last tab of a md-tabs element. I'm able to show the menu if I click on the tab label, but if I click on an empty zone of the tab it behaves as usual, showing the associated tab.

How can I extend the label behaviour to the whole tab?.

Here it is some code

```
<md-tabs class="stretch-height" flex md-selected="mbpSelectedIndex" md-border-bottom
   md-dynamic-height>
   <md-tab ng-repeat="tab in mbpTabs" md-on-select="onTabSelected(tab)">
      <md-menu context-menu>
         <div flex class="mbpTable" ng-right-click="$mdOpenContextMenu($event)">{{tab.title}}</div>
         <md-menu-content>
            <md-menu-item >
               <md-button  ng-click="showDeleteTabDialog($index, tab.title)" ng-disabled="mbpTabs.length<=1">Delete</md-button>
            </md-menu-item>
            <md-menu-item >
               <md-button  ng-click="renameTab($index, tab.title)">Rename</md-button>
            </md-menu-item>
            <md-menu-item >
               <md-button  ng-click="createTab()">New Tab</md-button>
            </md-menu-item>
            <md-menu-item ng-controller="watchlistsController">
               <md-button  ng-click="showWatchLists()">Create from Wathclist...</md-button>
            </md-menu-item>
         </md-menu-content>
      </md-menu>
      <md-tab-body>
         <div ag-grid="tab.mbpTable.table" class="ag-mbp mbpTable" id="mbpPanel"></div>
      </md-tab-body>
   <!-- this is the intersting tab-->
   </md-tab>
   <md-tab md-on-select="return">
      <md-menu>
         <div flex class="mbpTable" ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)">+</div>
         <md-menu-content>
            <md-menu-item ng-repeat ="tab in mbpTabs">
               <md-checkbox aria-label="{{tab.title}}">{{tab.title}}</md-checkbox>
            </md-menu-item>
            <md-menu-divider></md-menu-divider>
            <md-menu-item >
               <md-button  ng-click="createTab()">Create Custom Tab</md-button>
            </md-menu-item>
         </md-menu-content>
      </md-menu>
   </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

Comment: Move  ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)" from div to parent element. Keep moving up until you achieve the desired effect.

Comment: @AmirTalic doesn't work

Comment: Then you probably have some other event wired up to the parent element that is overriding your ng-click

Comment: I know it's difficult to override md-tab default behaviour because "there's some event wired up", but I'm looking for a way to get over it...

Comment: You haven't posted much of your code that could help us out here, but just by looking at your HTML, replacing `md-on-select` with `ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)"` should be working... It'd be great if you could post your code on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got out of it this way:

I added this in my CSS:

```
md-tab-item:last-of-type{
   padding:0!important;
   width:40px;
}
```

This the last tab button has no padding, and the whole tab button can be pressed without switching tab. The fixed width is related to the fact that the label is just a '+', so it would be too small with the auto width.